# Did the Swiss Air Force assist Austria in self-defence during the Yugoslav War?

Tags: aviation-history

I was told a story a story by a friend that went along the lines of:

- On multiple occasions, eastern european military aircraft strayed into Austrian airspace during one of the Yugoslav wars.
- Neutral Austria did not have air-to-air combat capability in their J35Ö Draken, so the Swiss Air Force F-5s helped them out instead.
- On one occasion, the Swiss air force came in and swiftly destroyed the aircraft in question before returning to base.

Note that I'm not completely sure of the exact sequence of events. I cannot find any reference for this story. Other aircraft downing during the war, especially NATO ones, are well covered.

Did this actually happen?

---

*Updates with a few notes:*

- This must have occurred before 1995 when the Austrian Air Force outfitted their aircraft with Sidewinders AAM.
- There is one case of a MIG-21 Pilot deflecting to Austria. Even this event is very vaguely documented.
- Several sources suggest neutral Austria was very shaken up and upset by the foreign fighter jets overflying their country.
- Information seems to be generally patchy, as this was before the days of the internet and there appears to have been much confusion and disorder.
- As much as Switzerland is perceived as neutral, Austria was also very much so since it was a small country sandwiched between the east and west during the cold war.
- Perhaps there is an international law that the Swiss were obligated to help, but kept it quiet out of concern of negative media publicity?

Comment: the second point to me sounds extremely unlikely, considering that we are speaking about [Swiss air force](http://www.defense-aerospace.com/article-view/release/151693/swiss-af-works-only-during-office-hours-but-allies-help-out.html).

Comment: @Federico I was equally surprised, but he seemed very confident in the story (then again he'd had a few beers). However, both countries were neutral and Austria appears to have lacked an air-to-air capability. Apparently from the Hague convention: "Belligerents may not invade neutral territory, and a neutral power's resisting any such attempt does not compromise its neutrality".

Comment: Might be better off moving this question to [History.SE](http://history.stackexchange.com/). I'd venture you'd be more likely to run into someone there who would have a good handle (i.e. be somewhat expert) on that time period.

Comment: @FreeMan flagged it for migration. If that doesn't work I can repost it myself...

Comment: The alleged Eastern European aircraft would have had to have been moving at hot-air-balloon speeds in order for it to be over Austrian airspace long enough for: a call from Austrian air defense to their national leadership, a call to their Swiss counterparts, a decision made to render this sort of lethal assistance, notifying Swiss air defense HQ, scrambling their interceptors, then the transit from Switzerland to Austrian airspace, intercepting the intruder, verifying that they were targeting a military (not civilian) aircraft, and getting final authorization to shoot. Sounds utterly bogus.

Comment: @Federico: In fairness to the Swiss Air Force, it should be noted that a) parts of the Geneva airport are actually in France; and b) in that part of Switzerland it would be difficult, if not impossible, to do a 360 turn in a jet while remaining within Swiss air space.

Comment: History.se won't like it either as it is an unfounded/unsourced story. Perhaps skeptics?

Comment: There was actually a period of several years the Austrian air force used F-5E leased from Switzerland. This was because the Draken was phased out before the Eurofighter Typhoons replacing them were delivered. During those years an intruder would have been shot by Swiss jet, **but** flown by Austrian pilots operating from an Austrian base.

Comment: Ref: http://www.airsceneuk.org.uk/hangar/2008/478austria/austria.htm

Comment: @CGCampbell: Skeptics.SE has a [requirement](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/864/faq-must-all-questions-be-notable) that questions must cite a notable claim.  You would need to give a reference to a widely read source claiming that these events took place.  "My friend told me a story" would be immediately closed on Skeptics.SE.

Comment: Also note that during the breakup of Yugoslavia there were numerous violations of Austrian airspace, which the Austrians were unable to respond to since their planes did not have any missiles due to an old treaty... So it is possible they might have called on the Swiss, if it was during the office hours...

Comment: @MikeFoxtrot I'm not entirely convinced this is a great fit for migration. If you think it belongs on one of our other sites, then feel free to ask it there, and see what their response is. You can also socialize the question it in their site chat rooms first if you want to get opinions about how good of a fit it might be. Up to you.

Comment: By the way, swiss doesn't have a 24h/24 7days/week air interception capacity anymore.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be in histroy SE

Answer (score 3):

I'm likely reading the same sources than you read. The chance of the event you are searching for ever occurred seems slim. As you wrote, Austria worked hard to maintain its neutrality policy.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austrian_Air_Force), it seems clear Austria was not using guided missiles before 1993, but indeed other weapons can be used to shoot down an enemy.

The article seems to be exhaustive for significant elements related to flights over the country by foreign aircraft, and still doesn't mention any destruction between 1970 and 1993.

There was a major incident in 1991 with Yugoslav MiG-21, but no mention of a shot down. This incident and the similar ones the same year led to the adoption of guided Sidewinder missiles by the air force two years later.

> From 1970, Austria purchased a total of 40 Saab 105 lightweight
>   multi-role aircraft with the intention to deploy them in trainer,
>   reconnaissance, interception and ground attack roles. As it became
>   clear in the 1980s that the sub-sonic aircraft were inadequate for air
>   combat and airspace interdiction, Austria purchased 24 reconditioned J
>   35 Draken fighter aircraft to supersede the Saab 105 as the Austrian
>   Air Force's main interceptor in 1988. The Saab 105 remained in service
>   as a trainer/surveillance aircraft.
>
> **Shortly after, the Draken saw their first major use in airspace interdiction starting 1991 during the Yugoslav Wars, when Yugoslav
>   MiG-21 fighters crossed the Austrian border without permission. In one
>   incident on 28 June a MiG-21 penetrated as far as Graz, causing
>   widespread demands for action.** Following repeated border crossings
>   by armed aircraft of the Yugoslav People's Army, changes were
>   suggested to the standing orders for aircraft armament.
>
> Since 1955, Austria's armed forces had been forbidden to operate any
>   guided missile system, including Air-to-air missiles and
>   surface-to-air missiles. In the post-Cold War environment, and with
>   gun-armed aircraft a relic of a past age, the Austrian Parliament
>   voted to amend this section of its state treaty and in January 1993
>   modern AIM-9 Sidewinder missiles were ordered from Sweden to arm its
>   fighter aircraft.

On the other assumption that Switzerland provided military assistance, again no mention of such cooperation until recent year, with the EU treaties.

It seems the overflights of Austria by non authorized aircrafts was quite intense --daily-- at the time of the Yugoslavia war.

You may be right when saying that Austria could be reluctant to disclose a shooting. The fact that it would have happened before the widespread use of Internet is not something that could prevent the event to be recounted online today.

Not relevant downing:

- Jan. 1992: Two [EU helicopters downed by Yugoslav MiG-21](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1992_European_Community_Monitor_Mission_helicopter_downing), Austria radars detected the downing.

Additional documentation:

- [The Austrian Air Force - In the Past and Today](http://www.bundesheer.at/english/forces/airforce.shtml)
- [Austrian Air Force](http://www.scramble.nl/orbats/austria/overview)
- [Austrian Air Force](http://www.globalsecurity.org/military/world/europe/at-fliegerdivision.htm)
- [A well documented list of interceptions over Austria](http://www.acig.info/CMS/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=104&Itemid=62)
- [Austrian Draken's on high alert](http://www.airpower.at/news01/1105_intercepts/)